# How to Trigger Visual Studio Team Services build for a GitHub Pull Request

Tags: github, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, pull-request, azure-pipelines

I have tried couple stuff but had no luck to trigger build on PR. See below for my triggers. Is there way to actually make this trigger work?

[image]

Comment: There's another section in the VSTS settings for "Path Filters." Do you have any of those set?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this for a VSTS build linked to a github repository, You can go to the build triggers section, where you will find option to enable build on pull request. Please see screen shot below.
[image: Enable Github Repo PR builds in VSTS]

Comment: This is not an option that's available in the triggers section for us. There is only one control above the Repositories filter and it's just "Trigger status" enabled/disabled.

Comment: Downvoting as there is no such option for me either.

Answer (score 0):

To trigger a github PR (when created) for VSTS build, you need below prerequisites:

> - Configure a web hook for VSTS
> - Develop your own website
> - Queue your build by REST API

Details steps as below:

#### **1. Create a web hook** (Pull request created):

In VSTS project page -> Service Hooks -> new -> Web Hooks -> Next -> **Pull request created** for Trigger on this type of event -> Next -> paster your website URL as the value of URL -> Test ->Finish.

#### **2. Develop your website with the function**:

When your website receive the Pull request created web hook information, then [queue your build by REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#queue-a-build).

Comment: is 1 and 2 are two different options or do I need to do both of them? And also what is copy of my website URL means? Why would I need to put it there?

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding? I just want to trigger VSTS build whenever I create a PR on my GitHub project. First step you mentioned seems like doing other way around?

Comment: You need both step1 and step2 to achieve your requirement.Copy website URL means you copy your website URL and paste it as the value of **URL** when you create the web hook. And I updated my answer which just trigger VSTS build (not to merge github PR).

Comment: @erincerol: You're saying "on my GitHub project": do you mean on your project in a *git* repository in VSTS?

Comment: I didn't mention "Github project", but based on your question, the answer is works for the situation that a git repo hosted on github, when a PR created on github, then a VSTS build will be queued.